# How to sum two double linked lists in one list efficiently?

Tags: java

For example listA = [3,6,7,4] and listB = [2,3,1] and the output has to be listC=[5,9,8,6]. This is what I have so far but it is not very efficient.

```
`public void sum(doublelist aList) {`
for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
     set(i, this.get(i) + other.get(i % other.size()));
}
}
```

Comment: How did you determine it is not efficient?

Comment: regardless how you see it, you will always have O(n) complexity as a minimum

Comment: The OP meantioned it being linked lists so the complexity of the code snippet is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

As you said you are using linked lists, you could navigate from element to element:

```java
public void sum(DoubleList aList){
    DoubleNode cur=this.head;
    DoubleNode other=aList.head;
    while(cur!=null){
        cur.setValue(cur.getValue()+other.getValue());
        other=other.getNext();
        if(other==null){
            other=aList.head;
        }
        cur=cur.getNext();
    }
}
```

This code assumes that your `DoubleList` contains a head node attribute named `head` from the type `DoubleNode` and `DoubleNode` has the methods `double getValue()`/`void setValue(double value)` for accessing the value and `DoubleNode getNext()` for retrieving the next element.

This should be more efficient as you don't have to query the list every time (`O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is totally dependent of what kind of List you are using.

But anyway, the best complexity you can get is O(n), you will have to iterate at least one time over each element of the lists.

The easiest is to use a ListIterator, that allow to set a value while iterating over the list.

```java
    void sum(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
        final ListIterator<Integer> it1 = l1.listIterator();
        final Iterator<Integer> it2 = l2.iterator();
        
        while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            it1.set(it1.next() + it2.next());
        }
    }
```